# Questions regarding Triac Driver circuit

Tags: resistors, driver, triac

Sparkfun's EL Escudo Dos breakout board uses this circuit for an EL wire driver channel, with R2 = R3 = 330. 
I was wondering what the function of  R2 and R3 is? Are they required? What would happen if they were simply replaced with a short?

EDIT: additional info
The HV lines are 110VAC and the channel will be driving EL tape (I think resistive and capacitive load?)

[image]

Comment: You're way too fast with accepting. Questions with an accepted answer get less new answers, which otherwise might be interesting too. I suggest to wait for a day or so, so that the question has time to go around the world. (I'm awake, but the rest of Europe isn't.) Or at least until there are a couple of other answers.

Comment: @stevenvh Hmm, good point. Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current limiting. The MOC3043 has a photodiode, and just like any diode can fry if not current limited.

Comment: I understand that, but I was asking about R2 and R3.

Comment: So was I. R1 is for the LED, R2 and R3 are for the photodiode.

Answer (score 4):

It's there to limit the peak current through the driver triac.
In the datasheet for the [MOC3043](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/motorola/MOC3042.pdf) this is given as 1A. So for a 115V RMS line with a pk-pk of ~170V, a resistor of around 180 ohms is suitable. The 330 ohms given is more suited to a 240V line, but if it works okay for your application then fine - the resistor value also sets the turnon angle, and too high a value may prevent the power triac getting enough gate current to turn on fully.

This [App Note](http://www.eetasia.com/ARTICLES/2001JUN/2001JUN15_AMD_AN.PDF?SOURCES=DOWNLOAD) has some good info on (optocoupled) triac driving.